# Can LiMn02 Lithium Manganese Dioxide batteries like CR123a be used in parallel?

Tags: batteries, battery-chemistry

I'd like to use multiple Lithium Manganese Dioxide cells in parallel in increase capacity. Using a single larger cell wouldn't fit the shape requirements for our ID.

LiMn02 are a primary cell and don't support charging.

Is it okay to connect them in parallel if they are fresh or is this likely to cause problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Lithium Manganese Dioxide Battery (Li/MnO2) - Maxell](http://www.maxell.com.tw/images/uploads/2014/10/Cy_CR_13e.pdf)

> Using different batteries together, i.e. different type or used and
>   new or different manufacturer could cause distortion, leakage,
>   overheating, explosion, or fire because of the differences in battery
>   property. **If using two or more batteries connected in series or in
>   parallel even same batteries, please consult with Maxell before
>   using.**

The danger with using cells in parallel is that if one has less charge then the other one will attempt to charge it. This could occur if one battery holder has a poor contact which causes the cell to discharge slower, or if they do not have the same state of charge when installed.

A safer solution would be to use a single higher capacity battery - and if the size of your device has to change to fit it then consider using a different battery type.